# android canvas.drawBitmap() paints whole bitmap in one color

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

im doing a simple paint program.

I'm drawing to a custom Bitmap and then draw this bitmap to the canvas in the onDraw method.

custom bitmap and canvas creation:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w - 150,h,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
canvasa  = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

when someone touches the screen a circle gets drawn:

```
canvasa.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
```

which works fine, but every time the bitmap gets drawn on Screen, every circle has the same color (the paints current color):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0, paint);
super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

So if i have a red circle, change the color to blue and draw another circle, both circles in the bitmap are blue. Why is that? And how do I fix this?

Comment: read about `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`

Comment: @pskink thanks man.... the one thing i did not check :D

Answer (score 2):

For what you are doing, it does not make sense to pass the paint color at the time of drawing to the canvas. This is how the current color of `paint` is appearing on the canvas. If you check the documents you see this can be `null`.

Also as has been pointed out in comments, the config of the bitmap is incorrect for what you want to do. I suggest `ARGB_8888` is more likely what you need here, so:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(w - 150, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

and:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```